# Main skipping over function?

Tags: c++, recursion, mergesort

I'm attempting to teach myself the basics of algorithms and data structures through a free online course, and as such, I though it'd give it a first shot at merge sort. This isn't really going to be used for anything so it's pretty sloppy, but I seem to be having a problem where main is not calling the MergeSort function.

The output is 00000000, (I assume because array is never assigned anything).  When I run the program through gdb the program seems to get to that line, and then completely skip over the function and go directly to the loop that prints the array.

Any thoughts? Am I missing something stupid?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *MergeSort(int array[], int sizeOf);

int main(){
    int numbers[8] = {5, 4, 1, 8, 7, 2, 6, 3};

    int *array = MergeSort(numbers, 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        cout << array[i];

return 0;

}

int *MergeSort(int array[], int sizeOf){

    int *leftArr = new int[sizeOf/2];       // Build arrays to split in half
    int *rightArr = new int[sizeOf/2];

    if (sizeOf < 2){                                     // Base case to end recursion
        return array;
    }

    else{

        for (int i = 0; i < (sizeOf/2); i++){ // Left gets first half
            leftArr[i] = array[i];
        }

        int j = (sizeOf/2) - 1;                          // Set point to start building 2nd

        for (int i = sizeOf; i >= (sizeOf/2); i--){
            rightArr[j] = array[i];                      // Build other half of array
            j--;
        }

        leftArr = MergeSort(leftArr, sizeOf/2);          // Call Recursive functions
        rightArr = MergeSort(rightArr, sizeOf/2);

    }

    static int *newArray = new int[sizeOf];     // Sorted array to Build
    int k = 0;                                                  // Iterators to build sorted func
    int m = 0;
    int p = 0;

    while (p < sizeOf){
        if (leftArr[k] < rightArr[m]){    // Left Arr's current value is less
            newArray[p] = leftArr[k];               // right arr's current calue
            k++;
        }
        else if (leftArr[k] >= rightArr[m]){
            newArray[p] = rightArr[k];
            m++;
        }
        p++;
    }

    //for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    //  cout << newArray[i] << endl;

    return newArray;                // Return address to new array

}
```

Comment: Stop assuming and run the program in [the debugger that came with your development environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger). Step through the program and watch what happens. Then you'll know for sure.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: OK. @πάνταῥεῖ's take on it is a little more polite than mine.

Comment: I've attempted to run the program through GDB (as noted), and it literally (seemingly) skips right over the call to the function...... So I guess I'm not exactly assuming because I have tried a debugger

Comment: @user4581301 It was designed to be _polite_ actually. It's a stock comment I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental design issue in your `MergeSort()`:

- your algorithm is recursive (that's perfect)
- unfortunately it returns `newArray`which is **`static`**.  This means that all invocations use the same instance of the same static variable (and overwrite the one returned by the recursive call).

You need to solve this by making newArray non static.  And at the end of the function, you need to `delete[]` the arrays returned by recursive calls in order to avoid memory leakage.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you!